# React router listen get params

Tags: react-router, redux

I am creating a blog using React/React-Router/Redux, and depending on the location, I want to show different blog posts, so if you are on `/category/cat1` you don't have the same list of blogs than if you are on `/category/cat2`.

So I'm thinking on storing the blog list in the store and my react component would pick it up from there so I could just have actions updating my state.

My thinking is listening on the `browserHistory` so I can get when the location changes and trigger the action which would update the new blog list, but I can't find how to get the params from my location path like I would from my component props `/category/:catName`

How can I get those params?
Is it actually the way to do it or should I use a different approach?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [version 2.0.0 upgrade guide](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/upgrade-guides/v2.0.0.md):

> RoutingContext -> Router render prop
>
> You can now pass a render prop to Router for it to use for rendering.
>   This allows you to create "middleware components" that participate in
>   routing. Its critical for integrations with libraries like Relay,
>   Redux, Resolver, Transmit, Async Props, etc.
>
> The default is basically this:
>   `<Router render={props => <RouterContext {...props} />} />`

This `render` prop on the `Router` is a hook into the render stage, and those props that are passed to the function contain the parsed route params, as well as lots of other routing context. Just make sure your function returns a `RouterContext`, or some equivalent, in the end.